# Assistance with a simple algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently learning algorithms from a book I have bought from Amazon but it is the worst book in the world, it shows examples but crucially doesn't show how to work the answers out.

so the first question I have is,

```
Prefix-Match(T[1..n], P[1..m]) {
i := 1 // point to current position in T[]
while(i <= n) {
// find a match for first character of P
while( i <= n && T[i] != P[1]) i++
if (i > n) return; // quit
len := 1
// match as much as possible
while(len < m && i+len <= n && T[i+len] == P[1+len]) len++
output i, len
i++
}
```

what would the output of this program be if T = [a,b,a,b,c,a,b] and P = [a,b,a]???

and secondly how do I work out time complexity of the algorithm, in terms of m and n?

Comment: There's no such thing as a java algorithm.  Algorithms are not language-dependent.

Comment: apologies I'm new to this subject field, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What language is this written in? It isn't Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all a question: what book you are talking about? If this is exactly a code sample from it, then it has to be terrible...

And now for the answer:

- this function runs through every element of T (this is the first `while` loop),
- then it finds the first occurrence of the the first element of P in the range from "i" to the end of the table T. In this case `i = 1`, because `T[1] == P[1]` (if T does not contain the first element of P then the function simply returns),
- then it looks at how many elements in T starting from `i` match subsequent elements in `P` (meaning that it will take element `T[i+1]` and check if it matches `P[2]` and same with `T[i+2]` and `P[3]`),
- it then prints the `i` it found and how many matches it found.

Basically this function finds all the subsets of T that match P. And the exact output should look like this:

```
1, 3
3, 2
6, 2
```

Tldr: the first number is the index at which the element `P[1]` is in the table T and the second number is the number of elements following it equal to its counterparts in table P.

But I do not know what was the author's intention - from what I understand the found subset doesn't have to completely match the P set, i.e. if we took: `T = [a,c,a]` and `P = [a,b,a]` we would still get the output `1,3`. There is no element that breaks the loop if the subsequent element of the found subset in T is different from its counterpart in P.

About time complexity there's plenty of articles on the web. If you want a book then CLRS Introduction to Algorithms or Algorithm Design Manual are my favorits.

Comment: thanks for that, this is exactly how the code is written in the book "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java (2nd Edition) by Robert Lafore (Nov 16, 2002)" avoid this book at all costs. I've just ordered the introduction to algorithms but am I right in thinking the output of this program would have been abaa???

Comment: Because of `T[i+len] == P[1+len]`, we will get 1,2; 2,1;3,1; in your small example

Comment: hope you will get what I've written after reading it a couple of times. It sure is hard for me to explain an algorithm via internet ;) But the output will most definitely be a pair of numbers. You can see that clearly in this line "output i, len" - both "i" and "len" are numbers. "i" being our index and "len" being the number of elements in the sequence matching elements in P (i do not think that "len" is the appropriate name here unless the author wanted to find longest sequences exactly matching elements in P which, in my opinion, he failed to do).

Comment: "i" can be anywhere between 1 and "n" (since the sequence can start at any element of T) and "len" can be between 1 and "m" since the shortest sequence matching elements of P can be 1 and the longest "m" (a sequence of elements in T matches all elements from P). So in this example "i" is between 1 and 7 and "len" is between 1 and 3.

Comment: yes but "i" will **always** be the index at which T[i] == P[1] so the only possible outputs here are "1,x", "3,x" and "6,x" as T[1]==T[3]==T[6]=P[1]. This is enforced by all the subsequent instructions in this function.

Comment: sorry my bad it returns when i >n

Comment: guys I just wanted to thank you again, I'm starting to grasp it slightly now, the explanations help in the actual understanding of the steps.

Answer (score 1):

> what would the output of this program be is T = [a,b,a,b,c,a,b] and P
>   = [a,b,a]???

The beginner way to do this is to take a pen and a paper and make a slot for each variable. Then go through each statement, just as a computer would and change the written variable values as result of the statement execution.

For example, if you start with T and P as above, you would first set values for T, n, P and m go through `i := 1` write `1` in the slot for `i`, then you would pass through  `while(i <= n) {` because (1 is < n) and so on...

When you do this a few times you will be be able to do it much faster.

I'm currently learning algorithms from a book I have bought from Amazon but it is the worst book in the world, it shows examples but crucially doesn't show how to work the answers out.

so the first question I have is,

```
 Prefix-Match(T[1..n], P[1..m]) {
  i := 1 // point to current position in T[]
  while(i <= n) {
     // find a match for first character of P
     while( i <= n && T[i] != P[1]) i++
     if (i > n) return; // quit
     len := 1
     // match as much as possible
     while(len < m && i+len <= n && T[i+len] == P[1+len]) len++
     output i, len
     i++
 }
```

what would the output of this program be is T = [a,b,a,b,c,a,b] and P = [a,b,a]???

> and secondly how do I work out time complexity of the algorithm, in
>   terms of m and n?

I am not convinced you are ready to workout time complexity, but think about how m and n affect the maximum time taken by the algorithm (or how long it will take you to do by hand):

- Does it depend on `m`?
- Does it depend on `n`?
- If it depends on both is it a function on `m+n` or more like `m*n`? That is, for the same sizt of `T` and double the size of `P` does it take twice as long?